# d3.js how to calculate percentage of bar on hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 chart and I want to show a tooltip on hover that shows the label of the bar section as well as the percentage of the total bar that the section is. My initial thought was to calculate the height of the section that's being hovered and figure out what percentage of that section the total bar is. I am doing that by adding this to my `mouseover` event(which I am currently logging when you hover):

```
d3.select(this).style("height")
```

This is working correctly, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I can't seem to find a way to get the height of the overall bar(with all sections accounted for) so that I can create my equation.

How would I go about this, or is there a better way to get the percentage?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg id="chart" width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [
  {month: "January", toys: 16591, games: 1047, books: 0, crafts: 5757},
  {month: "February", toys: 42337, games: 129, books: 835, crafts: 0},
  {month: "March", toys:  3385, games: 1053, books: 6260, crafts: 10},
  {month: "April", toys:  353, games: 3724, books: 4038, crafts: 0}
];

var series = d3.stack()
    .keys(["toys", "games", "books", "crafts"])
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
    (data);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }))
    .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .padding(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.min(series, stackMin), d3.max(series, stackMax)])
    .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var colors = ['#000','#000','#000','#000'];

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(series)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.month); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d){
        console.log(d3.select(this).style("height"));
        var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
        var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y"));
        var height = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("height"))
                
        d3.select(this).attr("stroke","blue").attr("stroke-width",0.8);
        svg.append("text")
          .attr("x",xPos)
          .attr("y",yPos +height/2)
          .attr("class","tooltip")
          //.text(Math.floor(d.y_pct.toFixed(2)*100) + "% of " + d.type );
    })

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

function stackMin(serie) {
  return d3.min(serie, function(d) { return d[0]; });
}

function stackMax(serie) {
  return d3.max(serie, function(d) { return d[1]; });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datum of each rectangle includes all the bars in that column in a `data` property:

[image]

The datum also includes the top and bottom (start and end) values for the rectangle itself: `d[0]` and `d[1]`.

Using this we can figure out a percentage:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
   var rectHeight = d[1] - d[0]; // The top and bottom vales of the rectangle.
   var columnHeight = d3.sum(d3.keys(d.data),function(k) {
      return +d.data[k]; // The sum of all bar rectangle heights in that column.
  });
  var percentHeight = rectHeight/columnHeight*100;
```

The units for rect height and column height above aren't SVG units, but are in the units of the dataset since we are accessing the data directly without scaling.

*d3.sum will ignore NaN or undefined values, a unary plus operator will coerce a string to a number, if this is not possible it will return NaN. Of course, if you have a month or x attribute that is a number, you'll need to remove it from the sum*

With this we get something like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg id="chart" width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [
  {month: "January", toys: 16591, games: 1047, books: 0, crafts: 5757},
  {month: "February", toys: 42337, games: 129, books: 835, crafts: 0},
  {month: "March", toys:  3385, games: 1053, books: 6260, crafts: 10},
  {month: "April", toys:  353, games: 3724, books: 4038, crafts: 0}
];

var series = d3.stack()
    .keys(["toys", "games", "books", "crafts"])
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
    (data);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }))
    .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .padding(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.min(series, stackMin), d3.max(series, stackMax)])
    .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var colors = ['#000','#000','#000','#000'];

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(series)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.month); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d){
        var rectHeight = d[1] - d[0];
        var columnHeight = d3.sum(d3.keys(d.data),function(k) {
           return +d.data[k];
        });
        console.log(Math.round(rectHeight/columnHeight*100)+"%");
    })

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

function stackMin(serie) {
  return d3.min(serie, function(d) { return d[0]; });
}

function stackMax(serie) {
  return d3.max(serie, function(d) { return d[1]; });
}

</script>
```